# Difference between a stationary and non-stationary k-armed bandit problem?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit

One of the challenges that arise in reinforcement learning, and not in other kinds of learning, is the trade-off between exploration and exploitation. Single-step reinforcement learning model is original of k-armed bandit.
But there are two kind of k-armed bandit problem: a stationary and non-stationary k-armed bandit problem,  What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit), in a non-stationary multi-armed bandit problem the "underlying model can change during play."

Answer (score 1):

In case of stationary bandit problems, the same bandit and distributions from which rewards are being sampled at each time step stays the same. This is called a stationary problem. To explain it with another example, say you get a reward of 1 every time a coin is tossed, and the result is head. Say after 1000 coin tosses due to wear and tear the coin becomes biased then this will become a non-stationary problem.